# Complicated Database Setup: Trying to display two field values that correspond to three other specific fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am creating a page to display a bunch of information from a database, but the database that I am working with is set up funky.

While there are about 15 columns, the ones I am concerned with are:
**Config_Name, Config_Type, Seq_Nbr, Question, and, Answer.**

Each Config_Type has a different set of Seq_Nbr Values. 
So I have a Config_Type called "_Hosting" which has about 12 different "Seq_Nbr" values. Each value corresponds to a different "Question" and "Answer" field. For example,

Examples:

> When any given Config_Name, Config_Type = _Hosting & Seq_Nbr = 60; the Question field will be
>   "Control Panel URL" and the Answer field will be
>   "www.examplesite.com/cpanel"
>
> When any given Config_Name, Config_Type = _Hosting & Seq_Nbr = 70; the Question field will be
>   "Control Panel Username" and the Answer field will be "*someusername*"

What I am trying to do is get all of the information displayed on one page.
I was thinking that I could use the code and query individual values for each section (from the examples):

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT Question, Answer FROM configs WHERE Config_Name='Company', Config_Type = '_Hosting', Seq_Nbr = '60'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
    $content = $result

?>
```

And then echo it into each individual

field:

```
<p>
    <h2><? echo "Control Panel URL"; ?><h2>
    <br></br>
    <h4><? echo $content; ?><h4>
</p></br>
```

But because I have to do this for 10+ "Seq_Nbr" values, this entire process seems tedious and unnecessarily repetitive. I know I could probably implement a switch() and have it go through different SQL queries, but I am trying to find a more efficient way to do this.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!
(I know the code isn't entirely correct, I am just trying to convey the method)

Thanks!

Comment: Well you're right in that you have to loop and repeat the query for each Seq_Nbr.....theres really no other way...but why can't you just query all and display all?  Wouldn't that be easier?

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: @KyleK - It might be easier, but then won't I have issues organizing the data? I want to be able to lay out the display page as "Question" - "Answer". // Will gooogle the query all and display all to see if that fits my needs.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary - Of course. Thank you. I'm working for a company and they haven't enabled MySQLi on the databases and I don't have permission. I will mention it to my boss to see if we can get that changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just query all and display all??

And use an ORDER BY to organize it however you want....

```
 //Google PDO to learn more, and how to connect
 //Connect
$conn = new PDO("...");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM configs ORDER BY Seq_Nbr";
foreach($conn->query($sql) as $val){
  echo "Name :". $val['Config_Name']."<br>";
  echo "Type :".$val['Config_Type']."<br>";
  echo "Question :". $val['Question']." | Answer :".$val['Answer']."<br>";
}
```

Forgive me if Im misunderstanding what you wanna do...

Also, Im using PDO in the example, just adapt what you need to if you're still gonna use mysql_*

Comment: Hmmm... That seemed to work. Now I'll just organize it into a table and go from there. Thanks for your insight! This way works much better than going one by one!

Answer (score 0):

if you want them all returned in one select, you might try an "in" clause.

```
$seq = "'60','70','80'";
$sql = "SELECT Question, Answer FROM configs WHERE Config_Name='Company' and Config_Type = '_Hosting' and Seq_Nbr in ( " . $seq . " ) ";
```

Comment: This is also a good way to do it. Thanks for your answer! I would upvote but I don't have enough rep.